# ODBC return values from iSeries on Linux

Tags: python, odbc, ibm-midrange

This is using pyodbc.

Okay, let's say I create a procedure on the iSeries using something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.MYSQL(IN WCCOD CHAR ( 6), INOUT WPLIN CHAR (3))
RESULT SETS 1 LANGUAGE CL NOT DETERMINISTIC   
CONTAINS SQL EXTERNAL NAME MYLIB.MYCL PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL
```

Then in Python I do something like this:

```
cust = 'ABCDEF'
line = '123'
sql = "CALL MYLIB.MYSQL('%(cust)s',?)" % vars()
values = (line)
c = pyodbc.connect('DSN='+system+';CMT=0;NAM=0')
cursor = c.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql,values)
```

Nothing in the variables shows the return value. The sense I get from seeing comparable code in other languages (ie. .NET) is that the ODBC "variable" is defined, then updated with the return value, but in this case neither "line" or "values" is changed.

I realize one alternative is to have the CL program write the result to a file then read the file, but it seems like an extra step that requires maintenance, never mind added complexity.

Has anyone ever made this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy cow, I got it working, but it takes two procedures, one to call the CL one to run the SQL statement.

For example (first procedure, this is what calls the CL program that returns a value in WPLIN):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.MYSQLA(IN WCCOD CHAR ( 6), INOUT WPLIN CHAR (3))
RESULT SETS 1 LANGUAGE CL NOT DETERMINISTIC   
CONTAINS SQL EXTERNAL NAME MYLIB.MYCL PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL
```

Second procedure (will call the first, THIS is the procedure we call from ODBC):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.MYSQLB(IN WCCOD CHAR ( 6), INOUT WPLIN CHAR (3))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN
DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT
FOR 
SELECT WPLIN FROM DUMMYLIB.DUMMYFILE;
CALL MYLIB.MYSQLA(WCCOD,WPLIN);
OPEN C1;
END
```

Then from an ODBC connection, we simply execute this:

```
customer = 'ABCDEF'
line='ABC'
sql = "{CALL MYLIB.MYSQLB('%(customer)s','%(line)s')}" % vars()
cursor.execute(sql)
print cursor.fetchone()
```

Et voila!

A caveat: The "DUMMYLIB/DUMMYFILE" are a single record physical file I created with a single byte column. It's only used for reference (unless there's a better way?) and it doesn't matter what's in it.

Maybe a bit clumsy, but it works! If anyone knows a way to combine these into a single procedure that would nice!

Comment: Why does `WPLIN` have to be `INOUT`? Can it just be `OUT`? If so, can you get rid of the dummy file?

Comment: It probably can be just an OUT and it would work. However the real problem is that in order for the ODBC interface to return the value, it must be returned as a result set, hence the "DECLARE C1" statement. In MySQL, I know I can do something like "Select 1" and it will return a 1. However the iSeries doesn't appear to support this functionality and forces the use of an actual table.

Comment: It's common for `SELECT` to require a table. In Oracle, a dummy table (called DUAL) is provided specifically for this purpose. I misread your code and thought the `SELECT` was retrieving a (dummy) value to pass *into* the CL.

Comment: Looking at various docs more, it seems you absolutely need at least one `SELECT` statement, because pyODBC (as of this writing) only handles result sets. Does your CLP do things which are hard to do in SQL?

Comment: In my case yes, the CLP is doing a whack of calculations for fetching information; since it's a core part of the ERP I had no interest in recreating the functionality in SQL or Python...I *thought* just calling the CL would be easier. Little did I know!

Answer (score 0):

First, you won't get any results at all if you don't fetch them.  When using pyODBC (or practically any other package adhering to [Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)), you have a couple of choices to do this.  You can explicitly call one of the fetch methods, such as

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

after which the result set will be in `results` (where each result is a tuple and `results` is a list of these tuples).  Or you can iterate directly over the cursor (which is a bit like repeatedly calling the `.fetchone()` method):

```
for row in cursor:
    # Do stuff with row here
    # Each time through the loop gets another row
    # When there are no more results, the loop ends
```

Now, whether you explicitly fetch or you use Python's looping mechanism, you receive a brand-new collection of values, accessed by the names you chose to receive them (`results` in my first example, `row` in my second.)  You can't specify Python variables to be updated directly by individual values.

Besides the [Python DB API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) spec mentioned above, you'll probably want to read up on pyODBC [features](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Features), and particularly on the way it handles [stored procedures](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/StoredProcedures).

Comment: Actually that doesn't work for return values; that works if there is data in a table to be returned, but the executing the call itself with a fetch statement actually results in an error. The actual error is: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

Comment: Here's a question: Could you use a CREATE FUNCTION instead and have the function return a "table"? Then you could (theoretically) use a SELECT statement to fetch the information...problem is after reading the 700 page Redbook on UDF I'm no closer to figuring out how to make it work :(